# '#' in aspx page parameter value creating issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whenever I am passing 2 parameters to an .aspx page with 1st parameter's value containing '#' then I am not able to fetch the value of the second parameter using "Request.Params["param1"]" in aspx.cs code.

Eg: When I hit the following URL (containing '#' in "assignmentname" parameter):

```
http://localhost/ReportingModule/summaryreport.aspx?assignmentname=School#College&submissionid=86900
```

then upon executing the code "Request.Params["submissionid"]", I don't get any value.

But when I hit the following URL (deleting the '#'):

```
http://localhost/ReportingModule/summaryreport.aspx?assignmentname=SchoolCollege&submissionid=86900
```

It works fine.
Whats the problem?

Comment: `#` in url will identify the following text as `id` of some container element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced '#' with '%23' and it worked!!

Comment: Please use [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of manually converting '#' to '%23'

Answer (score 0):

you can use `encodeURIComponent` for it like

```
link = encodeURIComponent(link);
```